# Call git hook after git reset --hard

Tags: git, githooks

Hoping someone can help,
From the documentation it looks like there is no git hook called after a "git reset --hard". Is this correct? Searching here the only work around I can see is placing an overriding function in your .bashrc ( something like shown below ).

```
git() {
    if [ "$1" = "reset" ] && [ "$2" = "--hard" ]; then
        DO SOMETHING
    fi
}
```

Instead of doing something like this is there an alternative? Can you create a "custom" hook or something?

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: I need to restart apache after a git reset is done.

Comment: `git reset --hard` is not supposed to be run regularly so no one needs a hook for it. Why do you want to run it frequently?

Comment: Who said I wanted to run it frequently? Why shouldn't there be a hook for it?

Comment: I suspect you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) -- my guess is your actual goal is to restart apache when file contents change.  You probably want something like `inotify` (or other related solutions)